# How to convert indentation style in a project directory

Tags: shell, indentation

First of all I am not sure that this is the place to ask this question. I am a web developer working on a medium sized team. We follow the same coding style using Lint/Hint tools. It happens eventually that we decide to change the style to use tabs instead of spaces, 3 spaces instead of 4 per tab..etc. Is there any tool that can help me convert the indentation style across all the project.

note: We are using JS/JSX/SCSS

Comment: Did you come over "astye" eventually ?

Comment: yea but I think it doesn't support JS/CSS ?

Comment: Related: [Tabs vs Spaces](https://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html)

Answer (score 1):

In `vim` you should be able to do

```
:%s/    /   /g
:set ts=3
:set noet
:%retab!
```

Depending on your current indentation you may need to follow up with

```
:%s/\t */\t/g
```

Using `set list` at the beginning of the process helps make it visible what exactly is happening

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Without list

[image]

For more elaborate syntax-driven reformatting I generally rely on an IDE (Eclipse etc)

Answer (score 1):

Changing tabs to 3 spaces:

```
expand -t 3  ...
```

Changing spaces to tabs:

```
unexpand ...
```

(man expand ; man unexpand for details)